# Unity 2018 and .Net Framework greater then 4.6

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, .net-framework-version

So Unity 2018 should support .Net Framework libraries above 4.6 (visit https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/28/updated-scripting-runtime-in-unity-2018-1-what-does-the-future-hold/).

I really need the .Net Framework 4.7.1 support for my project, but it doesn't works. The Scripting Runtime Version and Api Compatibility Level in the Unity Player Settings are setted to .NET 4.x. If i open the C-Sharp Project with Visual Studio 2017, i can install packages with NuGet, that needs the .Net Framework 4.7.1. After the installation the namespaces are available in C#, but if i go back to the Unity Editor, there are already errors in the console, that the namespace of the just installed package could not be found.

I have also tried to overwrite the  in the .csproj, but after i open the Project in Unity, it just overwrites it again back to 4.6. The whole compatibility stuff has already worked for me in the 2018.1b, but then i installed the stable version 2018.1.0f2 and now it works neither with the stable nor the beta-version. I also can't find a good guide that explains it, how to use / setup the .Net Framework 4.7.1 support in Unity.